# WSGI byte ranges serving

Tags: python, http, http-headers, wsgi, middleware

I'm looking into supporting [HTTP/1.1 Byte serving](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_serving) in WSGI server/application for:

- resuming partial downloads
- multi-part downloads
- better streaming

[WSGI PEP 333](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0333/#other-http-features) mentions that WSGI server may implement handling of byte serving (from [RFC 2616](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616) section 14.35.2 defines Accept-Range/Range/Content-Range response/request/response headers) and application should implement it if announces the capability:

> A server may transmit byte ranges of
> the application's response if
> requested by the client, and the
> application doesn't natively support
> byte ranges. Again, however, the
> application should perform this
> function on its own if desired.

I've performed some Googling but found little information upon which of the available WSGI servers/middleware/applications implement Byte-Ranges? Does anyone has an experience in the field and can hint me place to dig further?

EDIT: Can anyone comment, how I can enhance the question to be able to find an answer?

Comment: If you don't have luck here, try http://mail.python.org/mailman/listinfo/web-sig. Personally i don't feel byte ranges and wsgi fit together.

Comment: Will do. I've even prepared post in my Drafts, that is waiting a day or two to see if there is any answer here.

Answer (score 3):

I think [webob](http://pythonpaste.org/webob/) may do the trick, see the end of the [file example](http://pythonpaste.org/webob/file-example.html) for a range request implementation which efficiently seeks into the file being served.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to use WebOb and create the response as `Response(conditional_request=True)` or [subclass the WebOb Response object](http://pythonpaste.org/webob/reference.html#conditional-wsgi-application) making `conditional_request=True` the default.

When `conditional_request=True` and the request asked for a range, WebOb's `Response.app_iter_range` wraps the complete response to return only the requested range.

The [WebOb file serving example](http://pythonpaste.org/webob/file-example.html) shows how you would implement your own `app_iter_range` for cases where it is practical to get a range of bytes without generating the whole response.